# shared_preferences Flutter Add items

Tags: flutter

I expect that when I click the button I will add a single item that has brand and date in it in the Save Data function however I have no idea how to do that.Currently after each click they add tems however they are multiplied by themselves and that completely misses the point . I tried to add a single item however I get information about unsupported Error . In conclusion Please help

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'SharedPreferences Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> listItems = [];
  List<String> cart = [];
  final Map<String, dynamic> item = Map<String, String>();

  saveData() async {
    var date = DateTime.now();
    print('save data ');
    final Map<String, dynamic> item = Map<String, dynamic>();
    item['brand'] = 'item';
    item['date'] = 'date';

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (cart == null) cart = [];
    setState(() {
      cart = prefs.getStringList("cart") ?? [];
      cart.add(jsonEncode(item));

      
        listItems.add(jsonDecode(item));
     //<-- when i click button i want add one item card. on  but idk how
      prefs.setStringList("cart", cart);
    });
  }

  getUser() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var cart = prefs.getStringList("cart");
    setState(() {
      if (cart == null) {
        print('null');
      } else {
        cart.forEach((item) {
          listItems.add(jsonDecode(item));
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: listItems.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: listItems.length, itemBuilder: buildList)
                  : Center(
                      child: Text('EMPTY LIST'),
                    )),
          Center(
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: saveData,
              tooltip: 'Increment',
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 2,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(listItems[index]['brand']),
        subtitle: Text(listItems[index]['date'] ?? "null"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

     
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the complete page for the UI, and also add the event page and the state page that you have created for the bloc.

Comment: Just a suggestion that it seems you are using the future builder, But I think if you are using the bloc so you should bloc provided builders like BlocBuilder,BlocConsumer.

Comment: @SagarAcharya i update my question, pleas look.

Comment: Do you want this with simple state management or bloc pattern

Comment: simple state management add and save item with data and brand like snapshot[index]['brand'] , snapshot[index]['date']

Comment: from the code i see you mean to say the duplicate items are getting stored/saved when you tap the add icon.